# Javascript clock only works with embeddd code? how come?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok. so i am learning how to make a clock. went to W3schools to check out the code. now i want to mess around with it from military time and so forth. but i cant seem to get the code to work. when i take the code and put it in a JS file. i do not get the code running. If i put it in the HTML as embedded it works? what am i doing wrong here?

```
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds(); 
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
{
i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
```

HTMl is as follows

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>City Clock</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css">
</head>

<body>  
<h1> Austen's Clock</h1>



</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>` Should be in the `head`

Comment: `startTime` is unknown when the client interprets the `onload` attribute of `body`.

Comment: @Zeta I don't _think_ that matters - AFAIK inline scripts get wrapped in an interpreted `eval` block which is just passed that string so by the time that block is actually called the function is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `<script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>` into head of the document

OR

Rewrite you code like this

```
window.onload = function  startTime() {.....
```

Comment: That's not really answering "what am i doing wrong here?". It is a valid solution, however the OP should get to know _why_ it works.

Answer (score 0):

You've included the `<script>` tag after the first closing `</html>` tag - there shouldn't be any other elements after that, so they *should* be ignored.

Move it so that it's the last thing inside the `</body>` tag.

[FWIW, you code actually *does* work for me in both Chrome and Firefox on MacOS X.  In Chrome at least, the `<script>` element was automatically moved inside the `</body>` tag by the browser.]

Answer (score 0):

Recap of the previous replies:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>City Clock</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<h1> Austen's Clock</h1>
<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```